# Boomcatch Error Forwarder Failed

Tags: page-load-time, boomerang

I am using boomerang.js to measure the page load time of my web app. The boomerang is set and the beacon is working properly and sending data. Also, I am able to use boomcatch to receive this beacon data and it is able to process it. But when I try to forward the data using a forwarder to my simple web app page then it gives me the following error.

```
2018-06-07 19:38:29 INFO boomcatch: referer=http://127.0.0.1:8080/ui/ user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36 address=127.0.0.1[] method=POST url=/beacon
2018-06-07 19:38:29 INFO boomcatch: sending rt.firstbyte:20|ms
rt.lastbyte:1699|ms
rt.load:1699|ms

2018-06-07 19:38:29 ERROR boomcatch: Error: socket hang up
    at TLSSocket.onHangUp (_tls_wrap.js:1111:19)
    at TLSSocket.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
2018-06-07 19:38:29 ERROR boomcatch: 502 Forwarder failed
```

Comment: I would recommend posting an issue on GitHub. Stackoverflow isn't the right place for this.

Comment: @bluesmoon I have created a ticket in the github. Please look into it.
https://github.com/springernature/boomcatch/issues/92

Comment: I don't work on boomcatch, but the project owners are quite responsive